# Test database to use with a stored procedure support

Tags: database, oracle, unit-testing, junit4, hsqldb

I am working on a project that is using an Oracle database with stored procedures. I am unit testing with junit.

What I'd like to do is use an embedded database to emulate the Oracle database. However the application is using calls to stored procedures. The stored procedure takes in two variables and outs 15.

It would be simple to emulate a this stored procedure with a simple query to a table full of test data.

What embedded databases are available that can be used to emulate this functionality?

```
web_services.search_registrants(
    cert_nbr_in => :cert_nbr_in,
    last_4_ssn_in => :last_4_ssn_in,
    status_out => :status_out,
    cert_nbr_out => :cert_nbr_out,
    last_4_ssn_out => :last_4_ssn_out,
    last_name_out => :last_name_out,
    first_name_out => :first_name_out,
    mid_name_out => :mid_name_out,
    email_addr_out => :email_addr_out,
    st_address1_out => :st_address1_out,
    st_address2_out => :st_address2_out,
    city_out => :city_out,
    state_out => :state_out,
    zip_code_out => :zip_code_out,
    home_phone_out => :home_phone_out,
    work_phone_out => :work_phone_out,
    cell_phone_out => :cell_phone_out);
```

This is the java code, which works fine against Oracle.

```
 public Applicant find(String certNumber, String last4Ssn) {

    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Applicant applicant = null;

    try {
        try {
            conn = this.getConnection();

            cs = conn.prepareCall(
                    "{call NARS.web_services.search_registrants(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}") ;

            cs.setString("CERT_NBR_IN", certNumber);
            cs.setString("LAST_4_SSN_IN", last4Ssn);
            cs.registerOutParameter("STATUS_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("CERT_NBR_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("LAST_4_SSN_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("LAST_NAME_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("FIRST_NAME_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("MID_NAME_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("EMAIL_ADDR_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("ST_ADDRESS1_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("ST_ADDRESS2_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("CITY_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("STATE_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("ZIP_CODE_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("HOME_PHONE_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("WORK_PHONE_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter("CELL_PHONE_OUT", Types.VARCHAR);

            cs.execute();

            // 3 STATUS_OUT  OUT VARCHAR2 -- 0 = found, 
            // 1 = not found, 2 = expired certification, 3 = abuse
            String status = cs.getString("STATUS_OUT"); 
            System.out.println("status is: " + status);
            if(!status.equals("1")){

                System.out.println("certNumber " + cs.getString("CERT_NBR_OUT"));

                // Create new Applicant
                applicant = new Applicant(certNumber, last4Ssn);

                // 4 CERT_NBR_OUT        OUT VARCHAR2 -- 2 expired certification
                if(status.equals("2")){
                    applicant.setExpired(true);
                }
                if(status.equals("3")){
                    applicant.setAbuse(true);
                }

                applicant.setLastName(cs.getString("LAST_NAME_OUT"));
                applicant.setFirstName(cs.getString("FIRST_NAME_OUT"));
                applicant.setMidInit(cs.getString("MID_NAME_OUT"));
                applicant.setEmailAddress(cs.getString("EMAIL_ADDR_OUT"));
                applicant.setAddressLine1(cs.getString("ST_ADDRESS1_OUT"));
                applicant.setAddressLine2(cs.getString("ST_ADDRESS2_OUT"));
                applicant.setCity(cs.getString("CITY_OUT"));
                applicant.setState(cs.getString("STATE_OUT"));
                applicant.setZipCode(cs.getString("ZIP_CODE_OUT"));
                applicant.setHomePhone(cs.getString("HOME_PHONE_OUT"));
                applicant.setWorkPhone(cs.getString("WORK_PHONE_OUT"));
                applicant.setCellPhone(cs.getString("CELL_PHONE_OUT")); 
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if(cs != null) cs.close();
            if(conn != null) conn.close();

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return applicant;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using HSQLDB. I was able to write a stored procedures that return out variables. It's really cool. Here is an example of my HSQLDB setup script.

```
create table NARS_WEB_SERVICES.APPLICANTS (
  id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  cert_nbr    VARCHAR(10),
  status      VARCHAR(1),
  last_name   VARCHAR(40),
  first_name  VARCHAR(40),
  mid_name    VARCHAR(30),
  gender_code VARCHAR(7),
  lst_4_ssn   VARCHAR(4),
  ssn         VARCHAR(9),
  addr_1      VARCHAR(30),
  addr_2      VARCHAR(30),
  city        VARCHAR(30),
  stat        VARCHAR(2),
  zip         VARCHAR(10),
  home_phone  VARCHAR(20),
  work_phone  VARCHAR(20),
  cell_phone  VARCHAR(20),
  email_addr  VARCHAR(50));

CREATE PROCEDURE NARS_WEB_SERVICES.SEARCH_REGISTRANTS 
     ( IN  CERT_NBR_IN     VARCHAR(30),
       IN  LAST_4_SSN_IN   VARCHAR(30),
       OUT STATUS_OUT      VARCHAR(30),
       OUT CERT_NBR_OUT    VARCHAR(30),
       OUT LAST_4_SSN_OUT  VARCHAR(30),
       OUT LAST_NAME_OUT   VARCHAR(30),
       OUT FIRST_NAME_OUT  VARCHAR(30),
       OUT MID_NAME_OUT    VARCHAR(30),
       OUT EMAIL_ADDR_OUT  VARCHAR(30),
       OUT ST_ADDRESS1_OUT VARCHAR(30),
       OUT ST_ADDRESS2_OUT VARCHAR(30),
       OUT CITY_OUT        VARCHAR(30),
       OUT STATE_OUT       VARCHAR(30),
       OUT ZIP_CODE_OUT    VARCHAR(30),
       OUT HOME_PHONE_OUT  VARCHAR(30),
       OUT WORK_PHONE_OUT  VARCHAR(30),
       OUT CELL_PHONE_OUT  VARCHAR(30) )
   READS SQL DATA
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     SELECT status, cert_nbr, last_name, first_name, mid_name, lst_4_ssn, 
            addr_1, addr_2, city, stat, zip, home_phone, work_phone, 
            cell_phone, email_addr
       INTO STATUS_OUT, CERT_NBR_OUT, LAST_NAME_OUT, FIRST_NAME_OUT, 
            MID_NAME_OUT, LAST_4_SSN_OUT, ST_ADDRESS1_OUT, ST_ADDRESS2_OUT, 
            CITY_OUT, STATE_OUT, ZIP_CODE_OUT, HOME_PHONE_OUT, WORK_PHONE_OUT, 
            CELL_PHONE_OUT, EMAIL_ADDR_OUT
       FROM NARS_WEB_SERVICES.APPLICANTS 
      WHERE cert_nbr = CERT_NBR_IN
         OR lst_4_ssn = LAST_4_SSN_IN;
   END
.;
```

And that's it! So of course I set the database to my HSQLDB and tested against that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the approach suggested here http://chriswolf.heroku.com/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite/